# Amfast.TwistedChannel rpc dll not found

Tags: python, twisted, rpc, flexbuilder

I have tried to deploy a Flash website game used Python+Twisted+zope+amfast

When I run the server. It report a DLL NOT FOUND ERROR

```
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\amfast\remoting\twisted_channel.py", line 78, in __init__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\amfast\remoting\channel.py", line 144, in __init__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\amfast\remoting\channel.py", line 40, in __init__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\amfast\remoting\endpoint.py", line 22, in __init__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\amfast\encoder.py", line 1, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\amfast\encode.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\amfast\encode.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed
```

Meleesite.py:  error line TwistedChannel('rpc')

```
channel_set = TwistedChannelSet(notify_connections = True)
rpc_channel = TwistedChannel('rpc')
channel_set.mapChannel(rpc_channel)
```

I have installed rpclib in my python environment and check the Manual book from amfast googlecode. But got no idea how to fix it.

Thanks for help